# Backup Samsung s8 on ubuntu

Tags: backup, samsung

I wanted to ask if it's possible to backup my S8-Samsung on Ubuntu and if it is, do you recommend any specific software that it's free to use?

Comment: I don't think, that this is an Ubuntu related question, the backup should be made from Android or from Recovery....  Titanium Backup is afaik the app to go. For full backup you will need root access. But better to ask here: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @RoVo, i will ask my question there.